# regular expressions search random text between numbers

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression.

I have a random text and within the text are several numbers with the length 9.

Example:

```
Test1: "no results!"<br>
Test2: 123456789 Problems with ...<br>
Problem xyz -567891234 Problems with ...<br>
Test4: 987654321 kjdfk sakjsahfkldjasf kj
```

I want to extract the numbers that I have a result like this:

```
123456789, 567891234, 987654321
```

I can find the numbers with regular expressions:

```
\d{9}
```

My idea is to search for random characters until I find a number and then replace it by ", ". But I can't fing the regular expression for it. This is my try:

```
.*(\d{9}) and then replace with $1 ,
```

But that does not work. Can anybody help me please?

Comment: What is your actual problem?  You have a regular expression that finds numbers of the appropriate length so you simply need to use it with the regex library of your choice to extract the matches.  Changing the results into your desired format is likely easier to do with post-processing of the matches than in regular expressions directly

Comment: What's your expected output for the above input? Which language are you running?

Comment: With wich tooling/language ? are you stuck with it or do you allow other tools (like awk which sounds good for this task) ?

Answer (score 0):

A much better idea would be to use your programming language's string joining method. For example, in Python:

```
>>> s = """Test1: "no results!"
... Test2: 123456789 Problems with ...
... Problem xyz -567891234 Problems with ...
... Test4: 987654321 kjdfk sakjsahfkldjasf kj"""
>>> ", ".join(re.findall(r"\d{9}", s))
'123456789, 567891234, 987654321'
```

If you want to achieve the same result using only regex, you need to do this in two steps, neither of which is trivial:

```
>>> temp = re.sub(r"(?s)^.*?(?=\d{9})|(?<=\d{9})(?:(?!\d{9}).)*$", "", s)
>>> temp
'123456789 Problems with ...\nProblem xyz -567891234 Problems with ...\nTest4: 9
87654321'
>>> re.sub(r"(?s)(?!$)(?<=\d{9})(?:(?!\d{9}).)*", ", ", temp)
'123456789, 567891234, 987654321'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^.*?(\d{9}).*$
```

You can try this with `re.sub`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/34

```
import re
ll=[]
p = re.compile(r'^(?:.*?(\d{9}))+.*$', re.Multiline)
subst = "\1"
for line in test_data: 
    ll.append(re.sub(p, subst, line))
```